# How to make "less than" function in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, comparison, operators

As i am new to Prolog i made this program but having a lot of troubles can anyone help me?

below is my code:

```
android(samsung,s10,brown,90000).
android(huwawei,mate10lite,black,34000).
android(oppo,f9,blue,20000).

featured(nokia,1110,brown,10000).
featured(qmobile,q3,black,24000).
featured(gfive,g300,blue,30000).

amount(X,Y,Z,A):-
    android(X,Y,Z,A),
    A > 25000,
    featured(X,Y,Z,A),
    A>25000.

fun:-
    amount(X,Y,Z,A),
    writef("cellphone having less than 25K is",[X],[Y],[Z],[A]),
    fail.
```

i don't know what is the issue if anyone can help please help me out.
when ever i am calling fun it's returning false.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently,

```
amount(X,Y,Z,A):-
    android(X,Y,Z,A),   <---+
    A > 25000,              +--- exactly as for X,Y,Z, this is the SAME A 
    featured(X,Y,Z,A),  <---+
    A>25000.            <------- ... so you've already tested this!
```

you really want to have a `B`:

```
amount(X,Y,Z,A):-
    android(X,Y,Z,A),
    A > 25000,
    featured(X,Y,Z,B),
    B =< 25000.
```

And why do you **`fail.`** at the end of `fun`? That doesn't sound like fun at all!

Comment: i tried that even after doing that the answer is false.. i want the name, model and color of android and featured phone. but still the answer is false.

Comment: @FaizanHasan Because you call "fail" at the end.

Comment: brother still it's returning false even after i removed fail.

Comment: @FaizanHasan Well, that's because none of the `android(X,Y,Z,A)` are also `featured(X,Y,Z,B)`. So the possibility of shopping ends up empty. No solution. You have to extend the database....